# can a hacker aqquire access to a users env variables?

Tags: environment-variables

people say to put pwds in envariables instead of config files

can a hacker access env vars through a trojan?

if I put my pwds in a .php file, it will be interpreted and nothing goes to client

the file sys security is old and tested so I trust .php

but what about env vars?

Comment: this is a rather broad question. it's possible that a trojan can access everything your php program can access. you might want to try asking in https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are even older, and more tested than PHP.

Putting passwords in PHP is a terrible idea because you probably have multiple copies of your PHP files around (e.g. in source control, or in backups etc) which become alternate attack vectors.

Putting a password in the environment is preferable, because it's a different kind of system that the attacker has to penetrate first.

Even better yet, would be to put your passwords in a config file that is read by your PHP application, but exists in a vault or configuration repository that is only accessible to your operations team (who presumably has a need-to-know).

Of course, this is all moot if you don't have a strong secrutiy posture on your server or development environments.

Comment: every time the php config file is put in production, is must be edited with proper data. that edit can be automated.

Comment: But how is that edited data stored?  Who has access to it, and during what part of the process do the edits occur?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the security of the cloud service provider you are using (AWS, GCP, etc), most of whom are pretty secure. If you are talking about local development server, and pushing your code to an github, just make sure to add `.env` to your `.gitignore`, and you should be good.